# Parse dates from Javascript Date Object to regular datetime

Tags: javascript

How do I convert a date from JS Date Object to php datetime?

The following dates were converted to a Javascript Date Object from php datetimes:

```
"startsAt": "2015-08-15T10:46:00+00:00",
"endsAt": "2015-08-15T11:46:00+00:00"
```

converted using this syntax in javascript:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < events.events.length; i++) {
    events.events[i].startsAt = new Date(events.events[i].startsAt);
    events.events[i].endsAt   = new Date(events.events[i].endsAt);
 }
```

startsAt and EndsAt looked like so after the conversion:

```
startsAt: Date 2015-08-15T11:46:00.000Z
endsAt: Date 2015-08-15T11:46:00.000Z
```

Now my goal is to do the opposite in javascript (angularjs): Convert from Javascript Date Object to php datetime 2015-08-15T10:46:00+00:00. Any idea would help. Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: "regular datetime"? You mean a string?

Comment: "Javascript Date Object (string)" doesn't make sense. You can't have something that's an object and a string at the same time (er.. except the `String` object but that's beside the point.) What exactly do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to fix correct an answer below:

```
var rawDate = new Date();
var parsedDate =   [ 
       rawDate.getDate(),
       (rawDate.getMonth() + 1), //because getMonth() starts from 0
        rawDate.getFullYear() 
 ].join('-');

console.log(parsedDate); // output could be: 19-08-2015 for example
```

or just call any of the following to convert date object to string:

```
rawDate.toJSON();
rawDate.toISOString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got to parse it manually doing something like:

```
var rawDate = new Date();
var parsedDate = rawDate.getDate() + '-' + rawDate.getMonth() + '-' + rawDate.getFullYear();

console.log(parsedDate); // output could be: 19-08-2015 for example
```

Other possible ways of doing this could be found in [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).